# Mac is not remembering specific network

Tags: macos, wifi

I keep the option to auto-join preferred networks on wake.

However, after I reconfigured my router at home, my home network simply ignores that option.

I have already tried fixing HD permissions on Disc Utility. Didn't work.
What else can I do?

P.S.: The config is still working at work.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same thing happen to me.  Just create a new location with appropriate preferred settings and have that one connect.  You can delete the old one if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but didn't work here. I am thinking the problem is with my router then. I will reconfiguring it again.